# How do i insert a value in 1 table if it doesnt exist in another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, not-exists

I have two near identical tables and want to insert the values that exist in the 1st but not in the 2nd into the 2nd.

I do not care about updating the 1st table with missing values in the 2nd, just vice versa.

I tried this select as a test but it returned nothing even for values i know are missing

```
select * from table1 where Not Exists(Select * from table2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a field to join both tables together, something like this would work:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, col1)
SELECT id, col1
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table1.id = table2.id)
```

You can also accomplish the same thing with `NOT IN` and `OUTER JOIN`, but you'd still need the matching criteria from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the general sense with an `INSERT` statement like the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(Col1, Col2, ...)
  SELECT Col1, Col2, ....
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Criteria = t1.Criteria);
```

Similarly, the reverse can be done for `TABLE2 => TABLE1`.

You'll need to specify which columns make up the common criterion. Be wary that if the 2 tables are inserted into independently of eachother (as the requirement suggests), that autogenerated columns like `Guids` or `IDENTITY` will differ in the 2 tables and are not suitable as the join criteria.